# Eclipse CDT ASTRewrite not working

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I want to add some code to the C source code, so I try to use ASTRewrite.
My Github project: [cdt-rewrite](https://github.com/phibao37/cdt-rewrite)
My code:

[image]

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.eclipse.cdt.core.dom.ast.ASTVisitor;
import org.eclipse.cdt.core.dom.ast.IASTIfStatement;
import org.eclipse.cdt.core.dom.ast.IASTStatement;
import org.eclipse.cdt.core.dom.ast.IASTTranslationUnit;
import org.eclipse.cdt.core.dom.ast.gnu.c.GCCLanguage;
import org.eclipse.cdt.core.dom.rewrite.ASTRewrite;
import org.eclipse.cdt.core.model.ILanguage;
import org.eclipse.cdt.core.parser.DefaultLogService;
import org.eclipse.cdt.core.parser.FileContent;
import org.eclipse.cdt.core.parser.IncludeFileContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.cdt.core.parser.ScannerInfo;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.NullProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.Change;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        IASTTranslationUnit u = getTranslationUnit(new File("D:/test.c"));
        System.out.println(u.getRawSignature());

        ASTRewrite rw = ASTRewrite.create(u);
        u.accept(new ASTVisitor(true) {

            @Override
            public int visit(IASTStatement stm) {

                if (stm instanceof IASTIfStatement){
                    rw.insertBefore(stm.getParent(), stm, 
                            rw.createLiteralNode("callTo(1,2,3);"), null);
                }

                return PROCESS_CONTINUE;
            }

        });

        Change c = rw.rewriteAST();
        c.perform(new NullProgressMonitor());
        //String changedSource = someHowGetCode(c);
    }

    static IASTTranslationUnit getTranslationUnit(File source) throws Exception{
        FileContent reader = FileContent.create(
                source.getAbsolutePath(), 
                getContentFile(source).toCharArray());

        return GCCLanguage.getDefault().getASTTranslationUnit(
                reader, 
                new ScannerInfo(), 
                IncludeFileContentProvider.getSavedFilesProvider(), 
                null, 
                ILanguage.OPTION_IS_SOURCE_UNIT, 
                new DefaultLogService());
    }

    static String getContentFile(File file) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)))) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                content.append(line).append('\n');
        }

        return content.toString();
    }
}
```

But when I run this code, an exception is occur:

```
int test(int x){
    if (x < 0)
        return 0;
    int i, s = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < x; i++)
        s = s + i;
    return s;
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.formatter.ChangeFormatter.formatChangedCode(ChangeFormatter.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.rewrite.changegenerator.ChangeGenerator.generateChange(ChangeGenerator.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.rewrite.changegenerator.ChangeGenerator.generateChange(ChangeGenerator.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.rewrite.ASTRewriteAnalyzer.rewriteAST(ASTRewriteAnalyzer.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.dom.rewrite.ASTRewrite.rewriteAST(ASTRewrite.java:212)
    at Main.main(Main.java:44)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this exception?
Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK This code is dependent on running in OSGi, but you appear to have made a Java project with a `main`. You need to a plug-in project with a MANIFEST.MF that references what you require.

You can create an [Eclipse Application](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_an_Eclipse_application%3F) if you want to control the entry point to the program. If you want to graduate this rewriting code to be part of Eclipse/CDT, then different entry points such as an [Eclipse Command](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html) tied to a menu/toolbar/key combination may be what you want.

Comment: I am developing a plugin and also try to rewrite c code using the eclipse c ast parser. I getting the same NPE as mentionen in the question. Do you have any further advice? @Jonah Graham

Comment: Nothing new to add - if you are trying to use it outside like the OP then my answer still stands AFAIK. If you are using in OSGi, then you have a new question - which you seem to have asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67398617/2796832. Glad you solved your issue.