# Eclipse CDT ASTRewrite NPE

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, abstract-syntax-tree

I am developing a Eclipse plugin which should rewrite some .c source files.
I am using the Eclipse CDT AST parser, but I am facing a NPE when trying to save the adjustments to the AST.
I obtain the `IFile`(_file) to parse from a project of the active workspace. When executing the code below I am facing a NPE below.
NPE is thrown at: `Change c = rw.rewriteAST();`

```
Map<String, String> definedSymbols = new HashMap<String, String>();
String[] includePaths = new String[0];
IScannerInfo info = new ScannerInfo(definedSymbols, includePaths);
IParserLogService log = new DefaultLogService();
IncludeFileContentProvider emptyIncludes = IncludeFileContentProvider.getEmptyFilesProvider();
int opts = 8;
            
final IASTTranslationUnit tu =  GCCLanguage.getDefault().getASTTranslationUnit(FileContent.create(_file), info, emptyIncludes, null, opts, log);
final ASTRewrite rw = ASTRewrite.create(tu);
tu.accept(new ASTVisitor(true){
                
        @Override
        public int visit(IASTStatement statement){
            if(test) {
                test = false;
                rw.insertBefore(statement.getParent(), statement, rw.createLiteralNode("int i = 3;"), null);
            }
            return PROCESS_CONTINUE;
        }
});

Change c = rw.rewriteAST();
c.perform(new NullProgressMonitor());
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.formatter.ChangeFormatter.formatChangedCode(ChangeFormatter.java:95)
> at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.rewrite.changegenerator.ChangeGenerator.generateChange(ChangeGenerator.java:119)
> at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.rewrite.changegenerator.ChangeGenerator.generateChange(ChangeGenerator.java:107)
> at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.rewrite.ASTRewriteAnalyzer.rewriteAST(ASTRewriteAnalyzer.java:29)
> at org.eclipse.cdt.core.dom.rewrite.ASTRewrite.rewriteAST(ASTRewrite.java:213)
> at sheaperdexecuter.AstParser.parse(AstParser.java:155)
> at sheaperdexecuter.parts.SheaperdView$3.mouseDown(SheaperdView.java:140)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:196)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4209)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1043)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4026)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3626)
> at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
> at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
> at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
> at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
> at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
> at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
> at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
> at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
> at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
> at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
> at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
> at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
> at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1461)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1434)

A nearly identical problem is mention here: [Eclipse CDT ASTRewrite not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35335235/eclipse-cdt-astrewrite-not-working)
The answer to that question is to make sure that the program is running on an osgi framework. In my case the program is a eclipse plugin but I am still facing this NPE.

Can there by a problem with CDT? I am adding CDT via jar (`org.eclipse.cdt.core_6.9.0.201909091953.jar`) using the *Runtime* configuration tab of the plugin. (I would have added it to the *Dependencies* tab, but it is not available there)

//EDIT:

I have researched further in the CDT source code and in my case the `CCorePlugin` seems to not be initialized. If I call `CCorePlugin.getDefault();` I get `null` returned. I think this causes the exception mentioned above.
Do I need to bootstrap the `CCorePlugin` in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the fact that I added CDT via .jar using the **Runtime** configuration tab of the plugin.

My calls to the CDT environment (`CCorePlugin`, `CoreModel`, etc.) ended up not being related to the CDT running in the executing eclipse. Therefore I got NPE's on `CoreModel` and stuff.

I solved the problem by cloning the CDT source repo (https://git.eclipse.org/r/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git) and importing the projects to my Eclipse Committers IDE. (As explained here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Getting_started_with_CDT_development#Setting_up_the_Sources)

Afterwards I was able to add CDT to the **Dependencies** configuration tab of the plugin:
[image: Eclipse plugin CDT dependency]

After the dependency has been added the NPE's were gone and I could access the correct Instances of the workspace related models etc..

I hope this helps someone as it took me some hours to get the Eclipse plugin with CDT bootstrapped.